# Connect query on button in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I tried to connect my query code to the button. I want to show my 3D building features on a map related to their height values. When I click or slide my button, I want to see or highlight buildings that are called related to height. How can I connect them?

I tried like this :

```
    let a = document.getElementById("slider-1").value;

             if(a <= 10){
        extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "height < 10";
    } else if (a < 20) {
        extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "height < 20";
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a listener that will respond when the slider is moved

```
document.getElementById("slider-1").oninput = function() {
  if(this.value <= 10)
  {
    extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "height < 10";
  } else if (this.value < 20)
  {
    extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "height < 20";
  }
  //or just use the value directly
  //extrudedBuildings.definitionExpression = "height < " + this.value;
}
```